# Функция с бесконечным количеством параметров

Tags: javascript

В JavaScript'e есть функция `console.log()`, в которую можно передать много параметров.
В моём проекте есть нечто подобное:

```js
var MyObj = {
    log: function() {
        if (ENV != 'dev') {
            return;
        }
        //TODO more actions with console.log
    }
}
```

Есть функция, которая будет принимать параметры и передавать их в `console.log()`.
Но как достичь её универсальности, если вызовы будут, например, такими:

```
MyObj.log("var1=%s,var2=%s,var3=%s", var1, var2, var3);
MyObj.log("var1=%s,var2=%s,var3=%s,var4=%s,var5=%s", var1, var2, var3, var4, var5);
```

Как правильно передать в `console.log()` N аргументов, чтобы при этом не возникало `undefined`?

Comment: [Здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) есть примеры

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если достаточно просто вывести все аргументы на консоль, то:

```js
ENV = "dev";

var MyObj = {
  log: function() {
    if (ENV != 'dev') {
      return;
    }
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  }
}

MyObj.log(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Если нужно именно хитрое форматирование - то вам придется его написать вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Все аргументы передаваемые в функцию содержатся в переменной `arguments`